# data insertion into database using json

Tags: php, mysql, json

trying to insert data using json. code executed and each case a blank row is getting inserted instead of the specific given value into the table.. help me to correct this.. the code is given below.

```
   <?php
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   include('dbconnect.php');
   $json = isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : "";
   $new = json_decode($json, true);
   $sql="INSERT INTO emp(name,address,vicechancellor)
   values
   ('".$new['name']."','".$new['address']."','".$new['vicechancellor']."')";
   $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
   if($res)
   {
      echo "created ";
   } 
   else
   {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
   }    
   ?>
```

Comment: Your code is open to sql injections

Comment: please add var_dump($new, $json) output